# Maximum of a sound wave

Tags: waves, acoustics, interference

I have a question regarding an undergrad problem, and I thought it was going to be easy, but apparently I am missing some key element.

The exercise is the question IV-9 of the french Geipi-Polytech Physics 2018: http://www.geipi-polytech.org/sites/default/files/annales/gp_physique_2018_corrige.pdf

We have two emitters of spherical sound waves of the same frequency $f_1 = 110 Hz$ and wave length $\lambda = 3.11m$.

We define the position of a point $M$ by $(D_1,D_2)$ the distance from each emitter.
We are given the formula for a (maximum or minimum) of the wave: $\delta = D_2 - D_1 = n \cdot \frac{\lambda}{2}$.

We are given a table of values of intensities (maximum and minimum) at various places of space.

[image: Table of intensities]

The question is:
We emit a soundwave from these two sources but we double the frequencies. Does the point of coordinates $(D_1 = 0, D_2 = 127,75 m)$ corresponds to a maximum, a minimum or neither? And the correction says it's a maximum.

Obviously, if we double the frequency, we have a signal of frequency $f_2 = 2\cdot f_1 = 220 Hz$.

However, when I divide $\delta = D_2 - D_1 = 127,75m$ by twice the double of the spatial frequency, I expected to get an integer, or at least an quarter of an integer if I got the (1/2) factor wrong.

$\frac{\delta}{2 \lambda} = \frac{127,75}{2\cdot 3,11} \approx 20,5386$
 and $\frac{\delta}{\frac{\lambda}{2}} \approx 82,1543$

Neither of those are close to an integer.

I feel like this is super easy because it's undergrad, but I haven't done waves in years and I am honestly stuck. I feel like this is a super easy question, but I can't figure out something.

Thank you to whoever answers this.

Edit: It has been said in the comments by @npojo that I misread the coordinates. The point that is asked is of coordinates: [image: Orientation of the axis]
$(x = 0, y = 127,75m)$.
Since $x = 0$, then $y = D_1$.

I guess we have to assume that $D_2$ is the one given in the table?! It's not explicitely written out?! I guess we could have guessed because it is said in an earlier part that the sound engineer only moves along the y-axis, but it's not explicitely said that it is the case for the other part of the question. With such hypothesis, we know that if we double the frequency, the wave length is divided by 2 : $\lambda / 2$. However, we guess $D_2 - D_1 = \delta = 1,55 m$. So we compute $\frac{\delta}{\frac{\lambda_2}{2}} = \frac{\delta}{\frac{\frac{\lambda}{2}}{2}} = \frac{1,55}{\frac{3,11}{4}} = 2$. Which is great, because it means $n$ is even, which means it is a maximum.

Thank you npojo.

Comment: D2-D1=1.55 not 127.75.

Comment: And twice frequency is half wavelength.

Comment: @npojo : No, the question states that we are in the coordinates (D1 = 0, D2 = 127,75) and delta is equal to 127,75.

Comment: @npojo : Ok, if twice frequency is half wavelength, then delta/(lambda/2) should be integer, no?

Comment: The table says otherwise.

Comment: @npojo : The table says there is, with the original frequency, that when delta is 1.55, there is a minimum of the wave. HOWEVER, in the question, we have a new frequency, and we are asked at the coordinates (D1 = 0, D2 = 127,75m) to find whether it's a minimum, maximum or none; and the correction says it's a maximum. Thus my question.

Comment: yes. should be integer.

Comment: I agree it should have been an integer, but with delta = 127,75, it is not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89370/discussion-between-npojo-and-packsciences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been said in the comments by @npojo that I misread the coordinates. The point that is asked is of coordinates: [image: Orientation of the axis]
$(x = 0, y = 127,75m)$.
Since $x = 0$, then $y = D_1$.

I guess we have to assume that $D_2$ is the one given in the table?! It's not explicitely written out?! I guess we could have guessed because it is said in an earlier part that the sound engineer only moves along the y-axis, but it's not explicitely said that it is the case for the other part of the question. With such hypothesis, we know that if we double the frequency, the wave length is divided by 2 : $\lambda / 2$. However, we guess $D_2 - D_1 = \delta = 1,55 m$. So we compute $\frac{\delta}{\frac{\lambda_2}{2}} = \frac{\delta}{\frac{\frac{\lambda}{2}}{2}} = \frac{1,55}{\frac{3,11}{4}} = 2$. Which is great, because it means $n$ is even, which means it is a maximum.

Thank you npojo.